# Como puedo dividir una clase en subclases?

Tags: java, jframe

En c# existe algo llamado partial class que lo que hace es dividir una clase en varios archivos de esa misma clase y así poder fomentar una mejor legibilidad del código en cambio en java todo se programa en una clase llamada por ejemplo Mainframe.java que sin hacer casi nada me ha generado automáticamente casi 1000 líneas de código y como que me vuelve un poco loco eso... Existe alguna forma de al igual q en c# pueda dividir esa clase en clases parciales?

Comment: Una partial class no es una subclase. Es la misma clase, pero avisandole al compilador que la misma puede estar (no necesariamente) en varios archivos. Desconozco si java tiene algo asi, pero tene en cuenta eso.

Comment: Gracias... Me sería de mucha ayuda algo así en java para organizar mejor mi código

Comment: Y ¿por qué necesitas dividir tu clase en varios ficheros? Si tu clase es tan grande que se queda ilegible es que tienes problema de diseño de clase. Revisa tu código, refactoriza y no tendrás la necesidad de dividir en varios ficheros. Es la primera vez que oigo esto - querer dividir la clase en ficheros. Y eso que he visto código basura a montones.

Comment: Mmm no se como reaccionar a tu comentario creo que es un poco ofensivo... Lo que pasa es que de por si java genera código en mi clase principal y se me hace un poco tedioso tener que estar buscando donde están las cosas y tengo buena práctica de programación por eso prefiero c#a java pero no puedo x la universidad, solo qiero saber si existe algo para dividir en varias clases una misma clase en java en c# existe porque aquí no debería?

Comment: Lo mas remotamente parecido es con la herencia, y no se parece ni en pintura. Que yo sepa no existe nada similar. 1000 lineas de código en una clase no es ninguna una salvajada si esta todo estructurado. En todo caso se puede plantear si hay fragmentos del código que se pueden separar en digamos "subrutinas" que están en otras clases. El autentico problema y horror seria que 1000 lineas de código fuese un método.

Comment: No 1000 líneas de código no tengo un método eso como bien dices un horror... Me leí un libro sobre estructurar un programa en c# y decía que tener 1000 líneas de código en una clase era mala practica y la verdad que me parece muy bien ese consejo de ahí que c# implemente las partial class solo qiera saber si en java existe por lo que veo no voy a cerrar la pregunta gracias a todos